# Can't make Samba Share writeable

Tags: samba

This is my folder configuration from smb.conf

I can access this folder from my windows machine, but i don't have write privileges. I do need guests to be able to write to this folder. Forget security for a second... Why isn't this enough?

```
[Guest Share]
comment = Guest access share
path = /var/www/myFolder
browseable = yes
writable = yes
read only = no
guest ok = yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Samba is ultimately limited by the underlying filesystem permissions.  What do the permissions on `/var/www/myFolder` look like?  Do they allow anyone write access?

Comment: I'll check. if they don't, how do i "enable" write access to that folder? sorry, I'm a linux newbie.

Comment: [This document](http://www.geek-republic.com/2009/10/02/configure-anonymous-samba-sharing-in-ubuntu/) might help a bit.